# Latin characters (é) in workbook name not displaying correctly when downloaded

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am generating excel report in java using Apache POI. My workbook name contains some Latin characters. e.g **Résultats_détaillés**. I retrieve this name from properties file.
When excel is downloaded i see workbook name not displayed correctly.
**R+¬sultats_d+¬taill+¬sE**

Could anyone please help with resolution if any ?
Thanks In advance !!

Comment: Seems like it's being converted to a single character encoding from UTF-8 at some point (based on the accented characters becoming 2 separate characters).

Comment: Any way to handle it ?

Comment: Well sure, but if you're looking for a quick solution I don't have it. Check where you work with the workbook name and make sure that you're specifying the encoding if/where needed (i.e. if converting strings to bytes mainly).

Comment: Did you correctly set the encoding on your properties file, and correctly set the encoding on the reader when you read the properties back in?

Comment: How is this downloaded? Via `HTTP`? If so, read [rfc6266](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266#page-5) about the difference between `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=...` and `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=...`. See also the [Examples](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266#section-5). In general, I would avoid Unicode in file names because of: "Many user agent implementations predating this specification do not understand the "filename*" parameter."

Comment: Well 1 thing I observed is issue occurs only when I download report as zip file. In my case when more than 1 report is selected for downloading then they are compressed in ZIP file & downloaded. Then name of compressed file within zip become invalid. If i download single report then latin characters are displayed correctly in excel name.

Comment: @Viraj Udeg: Then the code which compresses the multiple workbook files into the one ZIP file does something wrong. What code is used for doing this?